# How to sort array of objects in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, vue.js

This is my relation function

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

And this is my controller

```php
public function allComments($id)
{
    $id=(int)$id;
    $post=Post::find($id);
    $comments=$post->comments;
    return dd($comments);
}
```

When i get comments by relation ship and i return it show

```
[
  {
    "id":48,
    "user_id":1,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"s",
    "created_at":"2019-08-24 02:53:54",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-24 02:53:54"},
    {
      "id":78,
      "user_id":1,
      "post_id":17,
      "isactive":1,
      "body":"s",
      "created_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06",
      "updated_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06"
    },
    {
      "id":79,
      "user_id":1,
      "post_id":17,
      "isactive":1,
      "body":"s",
      "created_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06",
      "updated_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06"
    },
    {
      "id":80,
      "user_id":2,
      "post_id":17,
      "isactive":1,
      "body":"\u06a9\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0631\u06cc",
      "created_at":"2019-08-25 06:48:51",
      "updated_at":"2019-08-24 06:48:51"
    },
    {
      "id":102,
      "user_id":2,
      "post_id":17,
      "isactive":1,
      "body":"\u0628",
      "created_at":"2019-08-25 01:32:39",
      "updated_at":"2019-08-25 01:32:39"
     },
     {
       "id":103,
       "user_id":2,
       "post_id":17,
       "isactive":1,
       "body":"\u0645\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062f \u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u0645",
       "created_at":"2019-08-25 01:35:13",
       "updated_at":"2019-08-25 01:35:13"
     },
     {
       "id":104,
       "user_id":2,
       "post_id":17,
       "isactive":1,
       "body":"\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0648\u0644\u0645",
       "created_at":"2019-08-25 02:01:32",
       "updated_at":"2019-08-25 02:01:32"
     },
     {
       "id":105,
       "user_id":2,
       "post_id":17,
       "isactive":1,
       "body":"\u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0634\u062f\u0645",
       "created_at":"2019-08-25 02:02:18",
       "updated_at":"2019-08-25 02:02:18"
     }
]
```

and then when i change controller and use sortByDesc on it

```php
public function allComments($id)
{
    $id=(int)$id;
    $post=Post::find($id);
    $comments=$post->comments->sortByDesc('created_at');;
    return $comments;
}
```

the result is:

```
{
  "3": {
    "id":80,
    "user_id":2,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"\u06a9\u06cc\u0631 \u062e\u0631\u06cc",
    "created_at":"2019-08-25 06:48:51",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-24 06:48:51"
  },
  "7": {
    "id":105,
    "user_id":2,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"\u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0634\u062f\u0645",
    "created_at":"2019-08-25 02:02:18",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-25 02:02:18"
  },
  "6": {
    "id":104,
    "user_id":2,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0648\u0644\u0645",
    "created_at":"2019-08-25 02:01:32",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-25 02:01:32"
  },
  "5": {
    "id":103,
    "user_id":2,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"\u0645\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062f \u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u0645",
    "created_at":"2019-08-25 01:35:13",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-25 01:35:13"
  },
  "4": {
    "id":102,
    "user_id":2,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"\u0628",
    "created_at":"2019-08-25 01:32:39",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-25 01:32:39"
  },
  "1": {
    "id":78,
    "user_id":1,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"s",
    "created_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06"
  },
  "2": {
    "id":79,
    "user_id":1,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"s",
    "created_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-24 02:54:06"},
  "0": {
    "id":48,
    "user_id":1,
    "post_id":17,
    "isactive":1,
    "body":"s",
    "created_at":"2019-08-24 02:53:54",
    "updated_at":"2019-08-24 02:53:54"
  }
}
```

I don't want it, I just want to sort it by *created_at* but it is show it like this (is this dictionary?)

Comment: you can remove semicoloun from your sortByDesc line of coding...

Comment: Is the resulted sorting right? you just want to remove the indexing numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the object keys after applying a filter like `sortByDesc()`, you could append `values()` then `all()` :

```php
public function allComments($id)
{
    $id=(int)$id;
    $post=Post::find($id);
    $comments=$post->comments->sortByDesc('created_at')->values()->all();
    return $comments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `values()` function of **Laravel Collection**. This will remove keys from the resulting collection.

If you want an **array** instead of a **collection** use `values()->all()`
.

```php
public function allComments($id)
{
    $id = (int) $id;
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $comments = $post->comments
                    ->sortByDesc('created_at')
                    ->values()
                    ->all();

    return $comments;
}
```

**Suggestion**

More fluent code.

```php
public function allComments($id)
{
    $comments = Comment::where('pots_id', $id)
                    ->sortByDesc('created_at')
                    ->values()
                    ->all();

    return $comments;
}
```